# How can I configure Pacman to warn user of an update for a certain package?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, upgrade, pacman, software-updates

I would like to be warned against an update to a particular package on arch linux using pacman.

I use some custom information in the header files for `gcc-libs`. But every time `gcc-libs` gets updated, these custom changes are reverted to factory default. These are not very difficult changes so I can repeat them every time they revert to factory defaults.

But I would like to have a warning every time that the package is going to be upgraded.

Eg, make an edit in `/etc/pacman.conf`. There is a field `IgnorePkg` and `IgnoreGroup`, but I don't want to ignore the update to the `gcc-libs` package. Any ways use of `IgnorePkg` and `IgnoreGroup` is discouraged.

I just want to be notified about an update to `gcc-libs`. I know before upgrading it asks your permission [Y/n], but is it possible to give a warning in yellow or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ignore a package you will get a warning that there is an upgrade available:

```
warning: ffmpeg: ignoring package upgrade (2:4.3.1-4 => 2:4.3.2-1)
```

But you can then still upgrade the package with `pacman -S ffmpeg`.

Instead of ignoring the package you could also write a custom hook that inserts the changes automatically (cf. [`man alpm-hooks`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/alpm-hooks.5)).

Alternatively you could also write a wrapper bash script for pacman which first checks for updates and warns you if gcc-libs is in the list and then proceeds with the install.